# Add users to organization team with Github API

Tags: curl, github-api

I'm trying to add multiple users to a team in a private group team using curl and the github API. However, something is off with my syntax and I'm not sure what it is.

I've tried:

```
curl --user "groupowner:password" -X PUT -d "" "https://api.github.com/orgs/ORGNAME/teams/TEAMNAME/members/USERNAMETOBEADDED/"
```

The github documentation, e.g., [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-collaborator) is helpful, but I'm missing something.Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326591/github-api-list-commit-status-when-repository-is-under-organisation?rq=1) it seems that another syntax may be possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting rid of the trailing slash and using the team membership API should do the trick:

```
curl --user "groupowner:password" -X PUT -d "" "https://api.github.com/teams/TEAMID/memberships/USERNAMETOBEADDED"
```

Comment: I get: 
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}

Comment: My bad - I just needed to find the teamid: http://fabian-kostadinov.github.io/2015/01/16/how-to-find-a-github-team-id/

Answer (score 4):

## OAuth, Organizations, etc.

Building on the answer from Hans Z. I'll show you how to invite an email address to join an organization and assign them to a team, all in one shot. You will also notice that I use an [OAuth "Personal Access" Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) header instead of a username and password. [You can (and should) do this](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) whether you are acting as an organization or a personal account holder.

```
# Assuming you have `export GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN=...` in your .bash_profile

# Define inputs
email="user@example.com"
org_name=DecaturMakers
team_name=Administrators

# Derive request data
team_id="$(
    curl -s                                                               \
         -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"                    \
         "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org_name/teams"                   |\
      jq 'map(select(.name=="'$team_name'")) | .[].id'
)"
json='{
  "role": "direct_member",
  "team_ids":['$team_id'],
  "email":"'$email'"
}'

# Send invitation
curl -s                                                                   \
     -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"                        \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.dazzler-preview+json"             \
     -d "$json"                                                           \
     "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org_name/invitations"
```

output

```
{
  "id": 12345678,
  "node_id": "MDIyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbkludml0YXRpb24xNjcwNTEwNg==",
  "login": null,
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "role": "direct_member",
  "created_at": "2019-08-20T20:53:49Z",
  "inviter": {
    "login": "RichardBronosky",
    "id": 12345,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjEzNjIw",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/12345?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/RichardBronosky",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/RichardBronosky/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "team_count": 1,
  "invitation_teams_url": "https://api.github.com/organizations/01234567/invitations/12345678/teams"
}
```

You may notice the extra header in the `curl` that sends the invitation. [That is explained here](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#create-organization-invitation).

### Bonus

#### [Get pending invitations for an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#list-pending-organization-invitations):

(You can use this to verify the results of the command above.)

```
# Verify results
curl -s                                                                   \
     -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"                        \
      "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org_name/invitations"                |\
  jq '[.[].email]'
```

output

```
[
  "user@example.com",
  "previous_user@example.com"
]
```

#### [Get the teams for an organization](https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#list-teams):

```
org_name=DecaturMakers
curl -sH "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"   \
     "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org_name/teams"
```

output

```
[
  {
    "name": "Administrators",
    "id": 123456,
    "node_id": "H4ShH4ShH4ShH4ShH4==",
    "slug": "administrators",
    "description": null,
    "privacy": "secret",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/teams/123456",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/teams/administrators",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/123456/members{/member}",
    "repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/teams/123456/repos",
    "permission": "pull"
  }
]
```

#### [Filter out the id](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) of a team in an organization:

```
team_name=Administrators
curl -sH "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"   \
     "https://api.github.com/orgs/$org_name/teams"   |\
     jq 'map(select(.name=="'$team_name'")) | .[].id'
```

output

```
123456
```

#### Get orgs you are a member of:

```
curl -sH "Authorization: token $GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"   \
     "https://api.github.com/user/orgs"
```

output

```
[
  {
    "login": "DecaturMakers",
    "id": 1234567,
    "node_id": "H4ShH4ShH4ShH4ShH4ShH4ShH4ShH4S=",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/events",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/hooks",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/issues",
    "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/members{/member}",
    "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/DecaturMakers/public_members{/member}",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/1234567?v=4",
    "description": "Code projects associated with Decatur Makers"
  }
]
```