# How do you add outside collaborators to repositories in your organization using Github Java API?

Tags: java, github, github-organizations, github-api-v3

I am trying to automate the process of instructors setting up an organization with repositories for their students. The repositories need to have a user be added as a collaborator because a continuous delivery server uses that user to make updates to the student repositories. The issue I am having is sending an invite to the user using the [Github Java API](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/). Here is the current code I am trying to use:

```
GHCreateRepositoryBuilder builder = this.organization.createRepository(this.prefix + i);
GHRepository repo = builder.create();
repo.addCollaborators(github.getUser("vcdep"));
repositories.add(repo);
```

The above code successfully creates the repository in the organization, but throws the following IO exception when the `addCollaborators` method is called:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation not applicable to a repository owned by someone else: TestOrganizationForDevOps
at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.verifyMine(GHRepository.java:1097)
at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.modifyCollaborators(GHRepository.java:507)
at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.addCollaborators(GHRepository.java:495)
at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.addCollaborators(GHRepository.java:491)
at wizard.GitHubController.createRepos(GitHubController.java:94)
at wizard.Controller.onButtonClickedFinish(Controller.java:260)
... 58 more
```

I have looked at other posts here, however, most of them talk about creating a team by inviting the users and then adding that [team to the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654997/add-user-to-organization-repository-github-api). But I am unable to do that because the user that must be attached to the repositories needs to automatically accept the invites and I already have a system in place that does that but only for repository invites, not team invites. I also looked at the Github Java API repository's [issue tracker](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/issues) and haven't found any similar to mine.

I thought I did not have the correct permissions at first but I am using a personal token from the account that owns the organization and that token has full privileges and I successfully authenticate using the Github Java API since the repository is created. I also tried adding the user as a member to the Github organization and then run the above code to see if that would help but had the same error appear. I have looked at the docs for both the Github Java API and just the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) itself and cannot see why the above is not working and I am wondering if it is an error or expected behavior. If any of you have any idea how to fix this I would really appreciate your help.

Also, I am using Maven to handle installing the GitHub API by Kohsuke. Here is a snippet from my pom.xml that handles the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
    <artifactId>github-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.80</version>
</dependency>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the source code from [kohsuke](https://github-com/kohsuke/github-api)?
In this source code the method 'verifyMine' doesn't exists.
This behaviour is perhaps caused because using a fork.

Comment: I am using Maven for install the library, so, it should be the official release and not some fork, but I maybe I am wrong. I updated my question to include the version I am using.

Comment: I checked out release 1.80. In release 1.80 you can only add Collaborators for your personal repositories. If you use release 1.94 this restriction was removed.

Comment: thanks so much I will check that version out! @J.Gerbershagen